# Convert Urn from item version have problem

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

I'm try to convert from item version get derivative urn but may be have something wrong. I know we are using `base64` to encoder, but when I'm try convert it have some missmatch:

Example:
I have item version is : `urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:j2R5fwxfTJq9DOsvX1p9ZQ?version=7`

And I'm try to convert it to get derivative urn` by use python code :

```py
import base64
item_version = "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:j2R5fwxfTJq9DOsvX1p9ZQ?version=7"
urn = base64.b64encode(item_version.encode()).decode()
# change character "/" to "_
urn = urn.replace("/", "_")
print(f"Derivative URN Of Version {version}: {urn}")
```

and the output is:

`dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpkbS5saW5lYWdlOmoyUjVmd3hmVEpxOURPc3ZYMXA5WlE_dmVyc2lvbj03`

But actually correct urn is :

`dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLmoyUjVmd3hmVEpxOURPc3ZYMXA5WlE_dmVyc2lvbj03`

So it have diffrence at :

dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDp**kbS5saW5lYWdlOmoy**UjVmd3hmVEpxOURPc3ZYMXA5WlE_dmVyc2lvbj03
and
dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDp**mcy5maWxlOnZmLmoy**UjVmd3hmVEpxOURPc3ZYMXA5WlE_dmVyc2lvbj03

Can I know the reason and why it missmatch with encoder `base64` ?

Any help is apprecited !

Answer (score 1):

Your version id is incorrect. For a version, the id should looks `urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.j2R5fwxfTJq9DOsvX1p9ZQ?version=7`. The `urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:j2R5fwxfTJq9DOsvX1p9ZQ` should be the item id.

However,

Please don't do the encoding yourself. You can get Derivative API from Data Management API directly.

https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/get-derivative-urn-accbim360-file-viewing-it-viewer

```json
"derivatives": {
                  "data": {
                      "type": "derivatives",
                      "id": "dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLlNrbjlTSkk4UVVpUkwwZHBtN29jNVE_dmVyc2lvbj0x"
                  },
                  "meta": {
                      "link": {
                          "href": "...."
                      }
                  }
              },
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just want to know how it work behind.